# ¿Cómo puedo organizar las escalas en un ploteo de dos variables diferentes en R?

Tags: r, excel, rstudio

```
INF<-ts(data$INFLACIÓN, start=c(2005, 1), frequency=12)
TD<-ts(data$DESEMPLEO, start=c(2005, 1), frequency=12)
plot(TD, ylab="%", xlab="TIEMPO" col=c("blue"))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(INF, ylab="", xlab="" col=c("red"))
```

Como pueden observar ahí he ploteado dos variables (TD e INF), pero cuando me sale el gráfico quedan con las escalas superpuestas, y la forma en la que deberían quedar no coincide como si se hiciera en un excel:

Como queda en R:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí, se puede observar que en la escala quedan datos superpuestos que no coinciciden de manera racional, pues queda los datos de INF que son menores superpuestos en TD que son mayores.

Ejemplo de como sería en excel:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo la minima idea de cómo organizar el grafico para que me quede parecido al de excel, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es eliminar la función `par` y colocar tu segundo `plot()` con la función `points()`. Así.

```
plot(TD, ylab="%", xlab="TIEMPO" col=c("blue"))
points(INF, ylab="", xlab="" col=c("red"), type="l")
```

Con eso se soluciona tu problema.

Comment: ¡Gracias amigo!